# How can the values from one dataframe be used to calculate the total number of values that are greater than or lesser than it in a second dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have different dataframes named: `step1`, `step2`,`step5` and so on and each one of them has a column named `BackGas_Flow_sccm`.

I used the `.describe()` on the `BackGas_Flow_sccm` column of every dataframe in order to use the 25% & the 75% to create new features like the `IQR`, `Max` & `Min` . After doing it, I dropped all the other columns and just kept the `IQR`, `Max` & `Min` columns in the dataframe giving the result as follows:

```
                    Max                 Min
step1   0.0061032863849765275   0.0023474178403755843
step2   0.0061032863849765275   0.0023474178403755843
step5   0.43849765258215967     0.4309859154929577
step7   0.4394366197183098      0.43192488262910805
step12  0.44178403755868545     0.43051643192488265
step15  0.44413145539906096     0.4291079812206573
step16  0.44272300469483566     0.43145539906103286
step19  0.8201877934272299      0.5610328638497655
step24  0.008450704225352117    0.0009389671361502306
step25  0.0061032863849765275   0.0023474178403755843
step26  0.0061032863849765275   0.0023474178403755843
step27  0.0061032863849765275   0.0023474178403755843
```

Now, I would like to use the values from this dataframe and calculate the number of values that are above the `Max` value or below the `Min` value, in the dataframes like `step1`, `step2`,`step5`.

I could do:

```
step1[step1['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'] > 0.0061032863849765275]
step1[step1['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'] < 0.0023474178403755843]
```

and it would give me the result as 424 and 135 respectively; meaning that there are 424 values in the `step1` df that are above 0.0061032863849765275 and 135 values that are below 0.0023474178403755843. But entering the numbers like 0.0061032863849765275 can be tedious.

So, is there a way this can be achieved in a more efficient manner?

**Edit 1**
[image: Image of dataframes in my Variable explorer window]

Comment: So how do you store those data frame ? in a list or in dict ?

Comment: Do you mean the dataframe I created with the `.describe()`?

Comment: *I have different dataframes* where are they , in list or dict, or just you save them into you local

Comment: They are all separate dataframes in neither list or dict. I'll attach a screenshot to give you a clear idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should store those dfs into either `list` or `dict`

```
d={'step1':step1,'step2':step2....}
```

Then we can `concat` it

```
s=pd.concat(d)['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'].unstack(0).describe().loc[['25%','75%']].T
```

After this we can then call for loop

```
for x in x.index:
    (d[x]['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'] > s.loc[x,'75%']).sum()
    (d[x]['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'] < s.loc[x,'25%']).sum()
```

Or without for loop

```
pd.concat(d)['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'].gt(s['75%'],level=0).sum(level=0)

pd.concat(d)['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'].lt(s['25%'],level=0).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: One question: Which dataframes do `[df,df]` mean in the `pd.concat` line?

Comment: @Junkrat hi edit my answer...and roll back to old version do not know why